# Codon alignment via Python?

Tags: dna, bioinformatics, proteins, sequence-analysis, sequence-alignment

I have pairs of coding DNA sequences which I wish to perform pairwise **codon alignments** via **Python**, I have "half completed" the process.

**So far..**

- I retrive pairs of orthologous DNA sequences from genbank using `Biopython` package.
- I translate the orthologous pairs into peptide sequences and then align them using `EMBOSS Needle` program.

**I wish to..**

- Transfer the gaps from the peptide sequences into the original DNA sequences.

**Question**

I would appreciate suggestions for programs/code (called from Python) that can transfer gaps from aligned peptide sequence pairs onto codons of the corresponding nucleotide sequence pairs. Or programs/code that can carry out the pairwise codon alignment from scratch.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you simply align the nucleotide sequences in the first place? Just use any alignment software.

Comment: Codon alignments serve a purpose, only this way you can obtain values of non-synonymous (dN) and synonymous (dS) rates of mutation.. which can then be used to obtain the dN/dS ratio used to infer selection

Comment: You can do that easily enough from the DNA sequence, no need to translate. Just align and read the codons from the alignment. You seem to be complicating your life needlessly. That said, this is probably too computer geeky for this site and you would be better off asking on [biostars](http://www.biostars.org).

Comment: Anyway, I would simply create a hash (a dict I believe they're called in Python) that links each amino acid to its codon. Then, once you have your alignment, read it and use the dict to translate back to the original codons inserting the gaps as you find them.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming and not biology. Bioinformatics questions are on topic here if they are about the underlying concepts, you are asking a very technical issue whose answer will be code.

Comment: Good point on the "too technical", hmm although I have seen various technical questions regarding software as well as lab protocol. Also if I did indeed use DNA alignments wouldn't I get overlapping codons due to gap sizes that are not a multiple of 3? I am doing codon alignments as it is standard procedure for dN/dS analysis - here is an explanation: http://www.hiv.lanl.gov/content/sequence/CodonAlign/codonalign_explanation.html

Comment: I am quite familiar with it, thanks :). I did my PhD on comparative genomics and reconstructing evolutionary histories, I've done more alignments than I care to remember. You need to know whether two codons are synonymous or not in order to get the dN/dS but not necessarily to translate them, it's just an easy way to check. Anyway, using my dict suggestion this is pretty trivial. Feel free to @ping me in [chat] if you need more help with it.

Comment: Store the genetic code in a dictionary; Use some default codon for each amino acid use `---` for a gap denoted in the peptide sequence by `-`.
The way to do it in python is:
`gcode={}`
`gcode['M']='ATG'`
`gcode['-']='---'`

... and so on

Then split the input sequence ans look up for each letter in the dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic process would be (in pseudocode, I don't know python well enough, I'm a Perl geek):

```
$seq1=ATGCCAGGCTGA
$seq2=ATGGGACCATAA;
for ($i=0;$i<length($seq1);$i++){
   codons1[$i]=amino_acid
}
for ($i=0;$i<length($seq2);$i++){
       codons2[$i]=amino_acid
}
```

At this point you will have two arrays or hashes or tuples or dicts or whatever holding the amino acid that corresponds to each codon position of the input seqs. You go and do your translation and dS/dN thing and you can then use these lists to map back to the original nucleotides:

```
for ($i=0;$i<length($ProteinSseq1);$i++){
  print codons1[$i]
}
```

You will need to adapt this to deal with codons correctly (i++ will only increment by one, you need to extract the triplets) and then to read the gaps but these are all programming issues that have nothing to do with the biological side of things.